# The type arguments for method cannot be inferred

Tags: c#, generics, casting

As stated in the title i got the compiler error CS0411 :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0411

What is not cleart to me is why, in this scenario, compiler is unable to infer the type.

```
MyType result = CurrentClass.MyGenericMethod(param); //<<== here i get the unexpected error

public static T MyGenericMethod<T> ( object param )
{
    ...some operation...
    return (T)result; 
}
```

MyGenericMethod is a proxy method that take some delegate as parameter, invoke them and cast result to the correct type (i oversimplify in the example).
In the first line, i have defined which is the expected type in the variable, so i expect the compiler can infer that this is the type the generic should have (MyType).

So why i have to type it explicitly? (i have memories where the compiler can infer that, is my memory broken or should i update VS?)

Comment: The compiler can infer it *if* the parameter uses the generic type parameter. Your one doesn't. Your invocation could be intended as `CurrentClass.MyGenericMethod<int>` or `CurrentClass.MyGenericMethod<string>` for example. The return type is *not* used in type inference.

Comment: @JonSkeet ah so my memory triked me.Thanks to clarification. I am a bit curious about this desing choiche, why return type is not used?

Comment: Very few things use "how the expression is being used" to affect how it executes - most of the type you can look at an expression and work out exactly what it means (assuming you know the types of all the constituent parts) without knowing whether the result is being assigned to anything, used as an argument to another method call etc. Exceptions to this are target-typed new, and anonymous functions.

Comment: `MyType 
result = CurrentClass.MyGenericMethod<MyType>(param)`